# How to change value of parameters in enum (Swift)

Tags: parameters, enums, swift

As all of you i'm new in Swift. I have no idea how to change parameter in enum, after it's creating. 
So. There are SimpleProtocol and SimpleEnum, which conforms this protocol.

```
//SimpleProto goes here
    protocol ExampleProtocol { 
    var simpleDescription: String { get }
    mutating func adjust()
}

//And SimpleEnum goes here

enum SimpleEnum : ExampleProtocol {
    case first(Int)
    case second(Int)
    case third(Int)

    var simpleDescription: String {
    get {
        var begining = "This is SimpleEnum with arg value : "
        switch self {
        case let .first(arg):
            begining += "One"

        case let .second(arg):
            begining += "Two"

        case let .third(arg):
            begining += "Three"
        }

        return begining
    }
    }

    mutating func adjust() {
        //here i want to increase the value of enum's parameter on five
    }
}
```

I can really imagine one solution, but i don't think it's good enough.
Main idea is that will recreate self with increased value:

```
case let .first(arg):
self = SimpleEnum.first(arg + 5)
```

Any idea?

Comment: I am not sure that this is allowed... but even if it were.. it sounds like a bad use of `enum`. 

What are you trying to achieve and why do you feel `enum` is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I'm using parameters in enum for the first time and I'm not quietly sure for which purposes parameters designed at all! I'm trying to discover all ways i can use it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a parameter. It's an associated value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't treat enums as mutable types. You'll be much happier. In the `adjust` function, just return a new enum value:

```
enum SimpleEnum {
  ...

  func adjust() -> SimpleEnum {
    switch self {
      case let .first(arg):
        return .first(arg + 5)
      case let .second(arg):
        return .second(arg + 5)
      case let .third(arg):
        return .third(arg + 5)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to consolidate these into 1 case statement? Something like the following:

`switch self {
      case let .first(arg), .second(arg), .third(arg):
        return .first(arg + 5)
    }`

Comment: @JoshSklar not unless you factor out the `Int` into a separate field apart from the `first`, `second`, and `third` tags. Then you can match on the int separately and add 5 (or apply whatever function) to it.